# function on entering admin list view

Tags: django, django-admin

I have an admin list view, that for every row calls an external API and therefore becomes costly. So I am looking for a way to make the call once on entering the admin list view:

```
@admin.display(description = "foo")
def some_action(self, obj):
    return do_some_expensive_call(obj)
```

I want to turn this into:

```
def run_once(self):
    self.results = {}
    self.results[key] = some_expensive_list_call()

@admin.display(description = "foo")
def some_action(self, obj):
    return self.results[obj]
```

Is there a method that should be used? Is it viable to override `get_queryset()`?

This is my approach so far:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super().get_queryset(request)
    self.status = {}
    LIST = [ITEM for ITEM in API_CALL.items()]
    for item in LIST:
        self.status[item[0]] = item[1]
    return qs

def some_action(self, obj):
    return self.status[obj]
```

Comment: I might not understand you correctly: You want to call multiple APIs once and display the results in one view to the user. Then you want to have multiple views / actions to perform on these results without losing the results (because on loss you need to call the APIs again). Depending on the actions you want to do you have to store the results somehow. But more information is needed here.

Comment: I added a sketch on how I approached this - my question was mostly, if `get_queryset()` is the right method to override.